# Laravel Imageable Type and Filtering

Tags: php, laravel

I have a product which is imageable

Product.php

```
public function imageable()
{
    return $this->morphTo('imageable');
}
```

And a vehicle that this morphs to

```
public function products()
{
  return $this->morphMany('App\Product', 'imageable');
}
```

I can call it fine with `$product->imageable->model` for example, if I want to get the vehicle model.

But how would I do this in a query, specifically like this:

```
$products = \App\Product::where('imageable_type', 'App\Vehicle')
```

And

```
$products->where($products->imageable->make, 'Ford')
```

That line above is pseudocode but its the principle I'm trying to achieve, is this even possible? I essentially want to be able to filter through the vehicles by Make, but that detail resides in the imageable model for the product.

Edit, after changing my query to:

```
if($make = request('make')){
                $products->where('imageable_type', 'App\Vehicle')
                ->whereHas('imageable', function($query) {
                    $query->where('make', request('make'));
                });
            }
```

as suggested below I get the following error:

```
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'make' in 
'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where 
(`products`.`user_id` != 3 and `products`.`status` = 0) and `category` 
= Cars and `imageable_type` = App\Vehicle and exists (select * from 
`products` as `laravel_reserved_0` where `laravel_reserved_0`.`id` = 
`laravel_reserved_0`.`imageable_id` and `make` = Tesla))`
```

When passing make as a request parameter

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
\App\Product::where('imageable_type', App\Vehicle::class)
    ->whereHas('imageable', function($query) {
        $query->where('make', 'Ford');
    })->get();
```

## update

in Product model add the `name` for `morphTo` relation:

```
public function imageable()
{
    return $this->morphTo('imageable');
}
```

## update

I think it will not work with you because there is a [bug](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5429) when the relation is `morpTo`

maybe you should do it in another way depends in what is your need:

Ex: 1

```
// in this way you will get all Vehicle made by ford and eager load the products, then you make some process to get all products.
$vehicles = \App\Vehicle::with('products')->where('make', 'Ford')->get();

foreach($vehicles as $vehicle) {
    // I put the condition because maybe there are some vehicles without products
    $productName = $vehicle->products->count() ? $vehicle->products->first()->name : '';    
}
```

#### Or

Ex: 2

```
\App\Product::leftJoin('vehicles', function(JoinClause $join)
    {
        $join->on('products.imageable_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
            ->on('products.imageable_type', '=', \DB::raw("'App\\Vehicle'"));
    })
    ->where('vehicles.make', 'Ford')
    ->where('products.imageable_type', App\Vehicle::class)
    ->get()
```

Comment: this is good thank you :) how would i go about passing a request to the where query, so for example if i passed `make` as a request parameter, how do i replace it with Ford? I'll edit my question to include the edits and the error I get.

Comment: Yes I was checking on the internet and there is a bug with `morphTo` relation check last update

Comment: Ah thats weird I was giving it a ready just now and I can see the problem.. thank you for this Aboudeh, I'll play around with your examples! :)

Comment: just quickly, would there be a way to reference the product name for example from the product table in the first example?

Comment: in the first example the function will return a collection of vehicle models, if you make a loop on you will get one vehicle model, so then you can access  the products property that contains a product collection i will write some code in the answer under the example

Comment: Thats exactly it, thank you for this, life saver! :)